# Responsive sticky menu not working after scroll

Tags: javascript, css, html, sticky, responsive

so I posted a question on here after messing with my code for several hours asking for help. Basically I wanted to make a responsive top menu that also stuck when you scrolled down to its level but for some reason, everything will appear to work but when the window was resized to be smaller than the minimum width to show the full menu, the drop down menu that activates then only works when it was still on top, not once you scrolled past it and made it sticky. I am currently learning html5 and css, but am pretty unfamiliar with javascript, so was trying to take examples I found off websites that allowed you to use their code (basically other tutorial websites) but wasn't having any luck, but have finally got it to work. I just wanted to post it here in case anyone is interested:

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/style01.css">

    <title>This is my title</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="logo">Logo place holder</div>
      <div class="coverimage">Cover Image place holder</div>

      <!-- Top menu is 44px in height -->    
      <div id="topmenu">
        <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
          <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Safety</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="contactright"><a class="contactright" href="#">Email Me: Text@email.com</a></li>
          <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <a href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">Here</a>
      Test
    </div>

    <script src="files/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="files/js/index.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The jquery.min.js needs to be there and could be downloaded from [here.](http://scriptsrc.net/)

css:

```
body{
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    margin: 0;
}

ul.topnav{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(60,60,60);
}
ul.topnav li{float: left;}
ul.topnav li a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: rgb(250,250,250);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.2s;
    font-size: 14px;
}
ul.topnav li.contactright{
    float: right;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: rgb(200,200,200);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: rgb(100,100,100);}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:675px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:675px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

/* This is the class that will be added or removed based on the scroll position */
.fixednav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.logo {font-size:40px; font-weight:bold;color:#00a; font-style:italic;}
.coverimage {color:#777; font-style:italic; margin:10px 0;}
#topmenu {background:#00a; color:#fff; height:40px; line-height:40px; letter-spacing:1px; width:100%; margin-bottom: -44px;}
.content {margin-top:10px; height: 20000px; padding-top: 54px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;}
.menu-padding {padding-top:40px;}
.content p {margin-bottom:20px;}
```

And the index js file I linked to:

```
// script for the sticky menu
var menu = document.querySelector('#topmenu');
var menuposition = menu.offsetTop;
stickMenu(menuposition);
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    stickMenu(menuposition);
});
function stickMenu(menupos) {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= menupos) {
        jQuery('#topmenu').addClass('fixednav');
    } else {
        jQuery('#topmenu').removeClass('fixednav');
    }
}

// script for the responsive menu
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

If anyone else found my topic because they had a similar issue, I hope this helps. :-)

Comment: Trim down the Un-Required Paragraphs and code to make it simple . Where you get some quick answers

Comment: Prasad Hey, thanks for replying, I wish I could, I'm learning what I could about css and html5, but don't really know much about js, so I really have no idea what is required or what isn't. I was really hoping that whoever here that could help me out could also help me get rid of what I don't need.

Comment: Also, I was trying to look online for how to code the other method that doesn't require cloning. That one's only problem is the jumping when the scroll reaches the element I want to stick, so the rest of the page jumps up, but I found an easy solution to that, which is to put padding in the main content and a negative margin of the same height on the sticky element. But for some reason I'm following the js from this site that shows it working but I can't get it to work... Anyone can provide me what I would need?

Comment: Woot! I did some more research and found a way to do it! I will edit my post to show it in case anyone is interested. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jquery was not working , i added the jquery again to the end of your document before the closing body.

```js
// script for the sticky menu
var menu = document.querySelector('#topmenu');
var menuposition = menu.offsetTop;
stickMenu(menuposition);
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    stickMenu(menuposition);
});
function stickMenu(menupos) {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= menupos) {
        jQuery('#topmenu').addClass('fixednav');
    } else {
        jQuery('#topmenu').removeClass('fixednav');
    }
}

// script for the responsive menu
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    margin: 0;
}

ul.topnav{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(60,60,60);
}
ul.topnav li{float: left;}
ul.topnav li a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: rgb(250,250,250);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.2s;
    font-size: 14px;
}
ul.topnav li.contactright{
    float: right;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: rgb(200,200,200);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: rgb(100,100,100);}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:675px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:675px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

/* This is the class that will be added or removed based on the scroll position */
.fixednav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.logo {font-size:40px; font-weight:bold;color:#00a; font-style:italic;}
.coverimage {color:#777; font-style:italic; margin:10px 0;}
#topmenu {background:#00a; color:#fff; height:40px; line-height:40px; letter-spacing:1px; width:100%; margin-bottom: -44px;}
.content {margin-top:10px; height: 20000px; padding-top: 54px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;}
.menu-padding {padding-top:40px;}
.content p {margin-bottom:20px;}
```

```html
   


  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="logo">Logo place holder</div>
      <div class="coverimage">Cover Image place holder</div>

      <!-- Top menu is 44px in height -->    
      <div id="topmenu">
        <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
          <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Safety</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="contactright"><a class="contactright" href="#">Email Me: Text@email.com</a></li>
          <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <a href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">Here</a>
      Test
    </div>

    <script src="files/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="files/js/index.js"></script>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"   integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    </body>
```